# Euler number with threads

Tags: multithreading

I have two classes to calculate Euler numbers.

The formula to calculate Euler numbers is a sum of 1/n!. n = 0 to infinity

This class calculates the factorial

```
public class E 
{
    public static double factorial(double number)
    {
          double m = number;
          if (number == 0 || number == 1)
          {
               return 1;
          } 
          else
          {
              return m*factorial(m-1);
          }
    }
```

}

And this class calculates the Euler number

```
public class Teste 
{
    static double e = 0;
    public static void euller (int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            double j = (double)(E.factorial(i));
            e += (1 / j);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        euller (100); // euller of numbr 100
        System.out.println (e);  
    }
}
```

I'd like to use threads. Each thread should calculate the factorial of a number.

For example, n = 10, threads number = 5

thread 1, calculate factorial 0 1, thread 2 calculate 2 3 ...

How should I include  threads in this code?

Comment: This is simply a "please write me the code" question as it's currently stated. You should "include threads" by writing code for a thread that takes two numbers and calculates the factorial of each of them. Once you have that working, write the code to use five instances of the thread, each one receiving a pair of numbers to calculate. Once you try the first half of that, and run into a problem, you can post the code you've written to that point, describe the problem you've encountered, and ask a **specific question** about the issue you're trying to solve. Good luck.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you want to use Threads?   As the factorial calculation implementation that you have is recursive (i.e. 3! depends on calculating 2!, and 2! depends on calculating 1!) - synchronizing the threads could be problematic.    If each thread runs independently, one will be duplicating the calculation work.   Re-writing the factorial calculation to not be recursive, might be more efficient than using threads.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pool thread, in your case with 5 threads and just execute them when you call factorial(i). there isn't much more then that.